# How to make my authentication token not expire?

Tags: python, authentication, flask, token, restful-authentication

I am using itsdangerous in order to create authentication tokens for my API. However, in my mobile application I am noticing that my token is regularly expiring. Here is the token generation-

```
def generate_auth_token(self, expiration=None):
    s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
    return s.dumps({'id': self.id})
```

I have also tried-

```
def generate_auth_token(self, expiration=None):
    s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expires_in=expiration)
    return s.dumps({'id': self.id})
```

However, my token is regularly expiring about every 10-20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not pass the token expire time.

```
 def generate_auth_token(self, expiration=None):
       s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
       return s.dumps({'id': self.id})
```

You can also see https://jwt.io/ to create token.